# Accessing data from rest API with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I´m developing an application with react and I found a big trouble manipulating the information from a rest API.

I have a fetch where the API by get method should bring me the customer id, but I always get an error like this:

> {error: "Customer not found"}
> error
> :
> "Customer not found"

[image: Image of the error]

I want to get an array with only the id of all customers, to do that I make this fetch function, but I don't know what to put in `.then((responseValue)` to get the correct array. I have tried with map function but then I get an error like:

> map prototyping is not defined.

Here is my code:

```
getHistory() {
    const {customer} = this.state
    fetch(
        DOMAIN+'/api/customers/'+customer._id, {
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
            }
        })
        .then((response) =>
        {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((responseValue) => {
            /*responseValue.map(function (v) {
                v.platform = v.app ? v.app.platform : null  })*/
            this.setState({customsId:responseValue});
            console.log(responseValue);
        })

}
```

Edit:

I have another fetch:

```
getCustomers(){

    fetch(

        DOMAIN+'/api/customers/shop/'+this.props.salon, {
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
            }
        })
        .then((response) =>
        {
            console.log(this.props.salon);
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((responseData) => {
            responseData.map(function (v) {
                v.platform = v.app ? v.app.platform : null  })
            this.setState({customers:responseData});
           //console.log(responseData);

        })
        .catch(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
}
```

The console.log inside the then function report me this array:

```
(22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{_id: "591d66f69ea5d935ed4b9ba9", shop: {…}, email:...
```

[image: Array with the customer _id]

So the question is, how can I access that id value with the first fetch or second fetch?

Comment: Looks like your api is not returning customer details for the customer id you passed.

Comment: Ok, when I run another fetch like this one: DOMAIN+'/api/customers/shop/'+this.props.salon, I recive the id customer like {_id: "591d66f69ea5d935ed4b9ba9", shop: {…},

Answer (score 0):

It's API error. It means that you send request with invalid customer._id, check this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve it:

I create this fetch

```
getCustomers(){

    fetch(

        DOMAIN+'/api/customers/shop/'+this.props.salon, {
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
            }
        })
        .then((response) =>
        {

            return response.json();
        })
        .then((responseData) => {
            responseData.map(function (v) {
                v.platform = v.app ? v.app.platform : null  })
            this.setState({customers:responseData});
           //console.log(responseData);

        })
        .catch(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
}
```

Then I created a handleClick to start the function and with the row.:_id I can print the id

```
 handleCellClick(y,x,row){
    //this.getHistory(this.state.orders);
    this.getHistory();
    var ab= this.state.orders
    this.setState({
        open:true,
        slideIndex: 0,
        newForm:false,
        customer:{...row,_id:row._id},
        order:{...x,customer:x.customer}

    });
    this.getCustomers(row._id);

    console.log(row._id);
    console.log(x.customer);

}
```